# If condition doesn't work?

Tags: jquery, if-statement

My code:
http://codepen.io/vincentccw/pen/qbGtF

I want to test whether my current css left's value is equal to 3% but jquery doesnt seem to validate....

my HTML:

```
<div id="slideHorizontal">
  this is a div
</div>
```

my css:

```
#slideHorizontal{
  position:relative;
  left:3%;
}
```

my jQuery:

```
$('body').click(function(){
        alert("you click");

  if($('#slideHorizontal').css("left") == 3+"%"){
      alert("0");
  }

});
```

Comment: post your code here please, we shouldn't have to go to another site to view it.

Comment: @PatrickEvans He posted a pen... That's perfect.

Comment: @AndréDion - no it's not! The code should be posted in the question as well.

Comment: Let's try testing the assumption that a percentage will be returned -> http://jsfiddle.net/fNwqY/, and we'll see it failing !

Comment: @AndréDion, it is not perfect, shouldn't have to load another site just to look at the code. Only when wanting test out his code is a pen/fiddle/what have you is needed. Especially for people like me on slow connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/PKyk6/)

```
var css = (Math.ceil( 100 * parseFloat($('#slideHorizontal').css("left")) / parseFloat($('#slideHorizontal').parent().css('width')) ) + '%';
```

`css` property return pixels so you can't compare it with `%`

so i have converted the `css` to `%`  using this above formula

```
$('body').click(function () {
    alert("you click");
    var css =Math.ceil( 100 * parseFloat($('#slideHorizontal').css("left")) / parseFloat($('#slideHorizontal').parent().css('width')) ) + '%'; 
    console.log(css);
    if (css == 3 + "%") {
        alert("0");
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but can you explain how does it work actually? Thanks

Comment: jQuery's `.css()` will return the *computed value* which you can observe: alert($('#slideHorizontal').css('left')); // 42.71875px Tushar's solution is to calculate `#slideHorizontal`'s position relative to its parent.

Comment: Shouldn't `$('#slideHorizontal').parent().css('left')` be `$('#slideHorizontal').parent().css('width')`

Comment: @PatrickEvans i tested that but it doesn't work for `$('#slideHorizontal').parent().css('left')` but it worked for `$('#slideHorizontal').parent().css('width')`

Comment: @PatrickEvans i tested this above code for different values and it worked.